# How to download file from server from button click event in android

Tags: android, apache-httpclient-4.x

I want to create an application using PHP webservices which can download file from server.

This is my Detail class:

```
public class ImportExportDataDetails extends Activity {

int id;
Button btnback;
public static final int DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS = 0;
private Button startBtn;
private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;



TextView txtname,tvfile1,tvfile2,tvdetail;
ImageView imgflag;
Button btnfile1,btnfile2;
String url1,url2,filenm1,filenm2;
private DefaultHttpClient httpclient;
private HttpPost httppost;
private ArrayList<NameValuePair> lst;

public static String[] image;
public static String[] name;
public static String[] file1;
public static String[] file2;
public static String[] fnm1;
public static String[] fnm2;
public static String[] detail;

private JSONArray users =null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_import_export_data_details);
    Intent i=getIntent();
    id=i.getIntExtra("id", 0);

    txtname=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtname);
    tvfile1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvfile1);
    tvfile2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvfile2);
    tvdetail=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvdetail);

    imgflag=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgflag);

    btnfile1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnfile1);
    btnfile2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnfile2);
    btnback=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnback);

    btnback.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ImportExportData.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
    httpclient=new DefaultHttpClient();
    httppost= new HttpPost("http://kalalunsons.com/webservice/web-import-export-data-details.php?import_export=1");
    lst=new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    lst.add(new BasicNameValuePair("im_ex_data_id", Integer.toString(id)));
    try {
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(lst));
        new details().execute();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    btnfile1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

             startDownload();

        }

    });
}
 private void startDownload() {
        String url = url1;
        new DownloadFileAsync().execute(url);
    }
    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
            case DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS:
                mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
                mProgressDialog.setMessage("Downloading file..");
                mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
                mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
                mProgressDialog.show();
                return mProgressDialog;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
    class DownloadFileAsync extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            showDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS);
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... aurl) {
            int count;

            try {
                URL url = new URL(aurl[0]);
                URLConnection conexion = url.openConnection();
                conexion.connect();

                int lenghtOfFile = conexion.getContentLength();
               // Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC", "Lenght of file: " + lenghtOfFile);

                InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
                OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/file.xlsx");

                byte data[] = new byte[1024];

                long total = 0;

                while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                    total += count;
                    publishProgress(""+(int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile));
                    output.write(data, 0, count);
                }

                output.flush();
                output.close();
                input.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {}
            return null;

        }
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
             Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC",progress[0]);
             mProgressDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String unused) {
            dismissDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS);
        }
    }

class details extends AsyncTask<String, integer, String>{

    String jsonstring;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            HttpResponse httpresponse=httpclient.execute(httppost);
            jsonstring=EntityUtils.toString(httpresponse.getEntity());
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return jsonstring;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        JSONObject JsonObject=null;
        try {
            JsonObject =new JSONObject(result);
            JSONObject jobj=JsonObject.getJSONObject("0");
            users=jobj.getJSONArray("import_export");

            name=new String[users.length()];
            image=new String[users.length()];
            detail=new String[users.length()];
            file1=new String[users.length()];
            file2=new String[users.length()];
            fnm1=new String[users.length()];
            fnm2=new String[users.length()];

            for(int i=0;i<users.length();i++){
                JSONObject jo=users.getJSONObject(i);

                name[i]=jo.getString("name");
                image[i]=jo.getString("image");
                detail[i]=jo.getString("details");
                file1[i]=jo.getString("file");
                file2[i]=jo.getString("file2");
                fnm1[i]=jo.getString("file_name");
                fnm2[i]=jo.getString("file_name");

                txtname.setText(name[i]);
                Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(image[i]+"?import_export=1").into(imgflag);
                tvdetail.setText(Html.fromHtml(detail[i]));
                tvfile1.setText(fnm1[i]);
                tvfile2.setText(fnm2[i]);
                url1=file1[i];
                url2=file2[i];
                filenm1=tvfile1.getText().toString();
                filenm1=filenm1.toLowerCase()+".xlsx";

            }
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), url1, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


}
```

In that case the logcat doesn't display any error.when i run this code it start progress of downloading,when progress finished i check my sdcard folder but it not display any file.the file was downloaded successfully but it displays as binary format,what can i changes in my code.and how can i display it in the sdcard.

Comment: post logcat as text.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code, XML, or logcat output. Please post all text as text, in the question itself. That said, you cannot pass an arbitrary `int` to `Toast` for the message. You'd have to convert it to a `String`. Also, you can't `Toast` directly from the thread `doInBackground()` runs on anyway. If you're just using it for debugging purposes, use a log print instead.

Answer (score 1):

you can use some library for network calls:-

retrofit-

http://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-working-with-retrofit-http-library/

also background and UI threads are separate threads. In UI thread, you can update your views and UI like toast messages and load an image.

here is a great article to learn about asynctask, read this first --

https://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2012/03/17/understanding-asynctask-once-and-forever/

Answer (score 0):

Issue: you are showing Toast in doInBackground() which run in separate thread. Remove Toast message from doInBackground() method

If you wanna show some info,use logs instead of Toast

Comment: Thanks but that is not my solution nothing changes when i removing the toast.